# Find all characters between the parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of mutual funds that I need to pull the ticker symbols out of. The list is like this:

```
FID SEL TELECOMM (FSTCX)07/29/1985
FID SEL UTILITIES (FSUTX)12/10/1981
SPTN REAL ES IDX ADV (FSRVX)09/08/2011
SA EMERGING MKTS FOF (FLILX)05/02/2012
SA INTL MULTI MGR (FMJDX)05/02/2012
FID ASSET MGR 85% (FAMRX)09/24/1999
```

I need to pull the 5 characters from each line that are sitting in the parens ().  I am then going to write to a new file, but for now I can't seem to return just the ticker (chars between the parens). I should get:

```
FSTCX
FSUTX
FSRVX
FLILX
FMJDX
FAMRX
```

Instead, it returns the entire line. Here's what I have (in C#).

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\(([A-Z]*)\)");

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\MyDocuments\\TickerList.txt");

string line;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)                
{
    Match match = pattern.Match(line);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to look at `match.Groups[1]` for your contents.

Comment: Wowsers, that was it.  However it is returning the parens as well. Shouldn't [A-Z] only pull the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(line);` does not involve `match`.

```
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And you can use `File.ReadLines`, too:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\(([A-Z]*)\)");

for (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\MyDocuments\TickerList.txt")) {
    Match match = pattern.Match(line);

    if (match.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Or maybe…

```
File.ReadLines(@"C:\MyDocuments\TickerList.txt")
    .Select(pattern.Match)
    .Where(m => m.Success)
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
```

(maybe)

Answer (score 2):

Regex + Linq

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("C:\\MyDocuments\\TickerList.txt");

var values = Regex.Matches(input, @"\((.+?)\)").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\(([^\)]*)\)");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eE1dC2)

And don't forget to print the matched group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try below regex and get matched group.

```
\((\w+)\)
```

[DEMO](https://www.debuggex.com/r/n4hR_PHvmvUyijgm)

String literals for use in programs: `@"\((\w+)\)"` for c#