# using Regex to find expression in middle of string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm New in Regex programming and I want to search for a pattern example:

19:09:41 PM : [ 0] 0.0-100.2 sec 796 MBytes `66.6 Mbits/sec` 0.273 ms 2454161/3029570 (81%) --> I want `66.6 Mbits/sec`

18:55:13 PM : [ 0] 0.0-99.1 sec 3847 MBytes `326 Mbits/sec` 0.068 ms 247494/3029365 (8.2%) --> I want `326 Mbits/sec`

So in the first step i want the Number Mbits/sec

This is My code snippet

```
Regex TP_PatternInt = new Regex(@"(?<TP>\d+) Mbit/sec");
Match TP_MatchInt = TP_PatternInt.Match(StringName);
string ResultInt = TP_MatchInt.ToString().Split(' ')[0];

Regex TP_PatternFloat = new Regex(@"(?<TP>\d+).\d Mbit/sec");
Match TP_MatchFloat = TP_PatternFloat.Match(StringName);
string ResultFloat = TP_MatchFloat.ToString().Split(' ')[0];

if (TP_MatchFloat.Success) Return ResultFloat;
else if(TP_MatchInt.Success) return ResultInt;
but when I run it I never get TP_MatchFloat.Success == true
```

What am I missing here ? Can someone propose a single pattern for both cases ?

Comment: How about `([\d.]+ Mbits\/sec)`? ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/vQ2hT3/1))

Comment: @Amal Murali 1.1.1.1 Mbits/sec?

Comment: @ArtyomKharlamov: The OP is extracting some information, not performing validation, so that regex should work for the most part.

Comment: @AmalMurali It's not clear, if he do want or do not want to get results that's not a valid number.

Comment: Are you looking for extraction of data or validation?

Comment: @Braj extraction , I have a long log and in there i have many lines like that that I want to print to other log ...

Comment: Then there is no possibility of  such invalid logs `1.1.1.1 Mbits/sec`

Comment: Try this out: `([\d\.]+\s?Mbits\/sec)`

Answer (score 2):

Two problems. One, your regex isn't exactly right, as others have shown. Two, you're declaring named groups, but don't actually use it to pull out your value, instead you use string parsing - regex is already doing string parsing for you, that's its purpose. Make the regex do everything you want.

So your regex should be something like:

```
@"(?<TP>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+Mbits/sec"
```

Then you should use the regex as follows:

```
string searchString = @"19:09:41 PM : [ 0] 0.0-100.2 sec 796 MBytes 66.6 Mbits/sec 0.273 ms 2454161/3029570 (81%)";

Regex regex = new Regex( @"(?<TP>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+Mbits/sec", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture );
Match match = regex.Match( searchString );

if ( match.Success )
{
    // If you only need the string representation of the value,
    // do this and you're done:
    string bitrateString = match.Groups["TP"].Value;

    // If you want to parse the string into an actual floating-point type,
    // do this:
    double bitrate;
    bitrate = double.Parse( match.Groups["TP"].Value );

    Console.Out.WriteLine( bitrate );
}
else
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine( "Could not match." );
}
```

Let's pull the regex apart a little bit to make it easier to understand:

- `(?<TP> ... )` - this is the syntax for a named capture, which you seem to already know about
- `\d+ (\. \d+)?` - Attempt to match the floating point value.

  - The `\.` means a literal period; `.` matches any one character so we have to escape it.
  - `(\. \d+)?` matches the '.66' part of the string. We put a `?` to make that optional, since floating point values can sometimes come out as "66" when the value is exactly "66.00". If you know that it will always be there, you can simplify the whole thing, shown later.
  - `\s+` - matches one or more whitespace characters. I tend to recommend `\s+` in case whitespace changes, perhaps if the software you're reading from starts to columnate output, in which case, they may add spaces, or replace spaces with tabs.
  - `Mbits/sec` - just match the literal string

As noted above, if you know that your floating point value will always have a fractional part, eg, "12.45" and never "12", then you can simplify the regex to:

```
@"(?<TP>\d+\.\d+)\s+Mbits/sec"
```

Keep in mind that not all software frameworks use exactly the same regex syntax. Since you're using C# / .Net regexes, I'd recommend something like [RegexLab](http://regexlab.codeplex.com/) or [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/). Other online testers might expect [Perl-compatible regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), that is regexes interpretted by the Perl programming language; PCREs do happen to be used by a wide range of software other than perl though, which is why there is often confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here ?

In this regex `@"(?<TP>\d+).\d Mbit/sec"` you might forget to escape decimal character that has a special meaning in regex pattern. Use escape character `\` to match it.

> Can someone propose a single pattern for both cases ?

You can try `@"(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.?\d?)\sMbits/sec"`

Pattern description:

```
\d+  one on more digits
\.?  zero or one decimal character
```

Input:

```
19:09:41 PM : [ 0] 0.0-100.2 sec 796 MBytes 66.6 Mbits/sec 0.273 ms 2454161/3029570 (81%)
18:55:13 PM : [ 0] 0.0-99.1 sec 3847 MBytes 326 Mbits/sec 0.068 ms 247494/3029365 (8.2%)
18:55:13 PM : [ 0] 0.0-99.1 sec 3847 MBytes 01.32 Mbits/sec 0.068 ms 247494/3029365 (8.2%)
```

Found 3 matches:

```
66.6 Mbits/sec has 1 group:
    66.6
326 Mbits/sec has 1 group:
    326
01.32 Mbits/sec has 1 group:
    01.32
```

Tested at [Here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: And what about 01.32 Mbits/sec

Comment: @ArtyomKharlamov let me test it.

Comment: can you please write a small code example of how would you use this Regax

Comment: @LordTitiKaka Do you know how to get the matched group?

Comment: Try `var res = Regex.Matches(targetString, @"(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.?\d?)\sMbits/sec").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();` or have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416151/regex-c-sharp-string-pseudo-wildcards-into-an-array/24416236#24416236) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392216/find-all-characters-between-the-parenthesis/24392274#24392274)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
(?<=\s)([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d*)?\s{1,3}Mbits\/sec
```

http://regex101.com/r/eC6gR7/2

Comment: What about `1.1.1.1 Mbits/sec`? This would still match `.1 Mbits/sec` in that.

Comment: @AmalMurali Is it a valid Mbits/sec?

Comment: @Braj: AFAIK, no, that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex
    ^.*\s((\d{1,10})(.\d{1,10})?)\sMbits/sec.*$
you can get three groups: first - whole number, second - integral, third - fractional.